# How to access the values of a list that is inside tasks.py via views.py while the list is filling and the task is not finished yet?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, python-multithreading, django-celery

I have a simple function in **views.py** and I need to call a task in this function to do something and put the result in a list. So, I need to read the first 10 values of the list while the list is filling by the task and it's not complete yet (or task is not finished yet). How can I do this?
I use celery 4.3.0(rhubrab) and RabbitMQ 3.7.14 for task handling in Django 2.1.7

Since more than one user may want to use website, therefore I think it needs to call a worker for each request so I try to use class based task but this is not recommended in celery documentation (although was not resolve my trouble again) and I use functional task.

The view function and task function which I expected to work is as follows:

**views.py :**

```
from .tasks import fetch

def search_result(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_task = fetch.delay(arg1, arg2)
        my_task_id = my_task.task_id
    while True:
        if len(fetch.MAIN_LIST) > 9 :
            initial = fetch.MAIN_LIST[0:10]
            return HttpResponse(temp.render({'initial' : initial}, request))
        elif AsyncResult(my_task_id).ready():
            initial = fetch.main_list.get()
            return HttpResponse(temp.render({'initial' : initial}, request))
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
```

**tasks.py :**

```
@shared_task
def fetch(larg1, arg2):
    main_list = []
    # do something and get result
    main_list.append(result)
    # this task is continuously doing until unknown time
```

It needs to say celery configuration is correct because I test it in small scale when fetch returns `MAIN_LIST` but in real project I can't wait for task is over and `MAIN_LIST` be return.

Comment: i think you would need to use client-side ajax polling to get results of tasks progress status, see for example: https://buildwithdjango.com/blog/post/celery-progress-bars/

Comment: for now i need to know is it possible to read from a list which is filling by a task or not? if i can do it so i can do everything.